# Powershell - Call Unique Values in a ForEach loop from Two Variables to execute a PowerCLI command

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powercli

I am trying to write a script to bring network cards back online, after a port conflict.

I have a list of VMs stored in one variable (`$VDILIST`) and have a list of available port numbers stored in a second variable (`$FREEPORT`).

How do I assign a port number to each of the new VM Network cards. I included a line (remarked out) how to do it for one. I know how to either process a single list ForEach loop. However, I can not figure out how to process these values from two seperate variables.

```
Port               VM
----              ----
01                 PC-A 
02                 PC-B
03                 PC-C
04                 PC-D
```

I want to assign Port 01 ot PC-A then move to the next and assign Port 02 to PC-B. Then continue on from there.

Thank you for your help.

```
$VDI = "vdi-win7v5-*"
$PORTGROUP = "Enterprise"

$VDILIST = @(Get-VM $VDI)
$FREEPORT = Get-dvPgFreePort -PortGroup $PortGroup -Number ($VDILIST).count

###USED FOR SINGLE COMPUTER
###Get-VM vdi-win7v2-30 |Get-NetworkAdapter|Set-NetworkAdapter -PortKey $FREEPORT -DistributedSwitch chsdc-nexus1000v -Connected:$TRUE -Confirm:$False
```

Comment: Are we ensured that your list of open ports will be the same size as your list of VMs? If not are you looking to assign as many VM:Port pairs as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `$VDILIST` and `$FREEPORT` have exactly the same number of items:

```
For ($i = 0; $i -lt $VDILIST.count; $i++)
{
    Get-VM $VDILIST[$i] |Get-NetworkAdapter|Set-NetworkAdapter -PortKey $FREEPORT[$i] -DistributedSwitch chsdc-nexus1000v -Connected:$TRUE -Confirm:$False
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help with this. It worked great. I was circling around it, and you hit it perfectly. Thanks again.